# Arithmetic network to compute floor of binary logarithm

Tags: arithmetic

I wonder how to build efficient arithmetic network (using logical gates only) to compute floor of binary logarithm of the given input number. I have read some articles on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) about this problem, respectively its implementation in C/C++ using bitwise operations only.

[Stackoverflow: Computing the floor of log_2(x) using only bitwise operators in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442088/computing-the-floor-of-log-2x-using-only-bitwise-operators-in-c) 
[Stackoverflow: Computing the floor log of a binary number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561596/computing-the-floor-log-of-a-binary-number) 
[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) 
 
I am pretty sure there's a simpler way to get this done. Using De Bruijn sequences seems to be a magic for me.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165058/755

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done with a fairly simple log-depth circuit without resorting to such hacks that only really make sense in software.

The "position of most significant set bit" function `pmsb` can be defined recursively:

$\begin{split}pmsb(``0") &= Nil \\
pmsb(``1") &= Nil \\
pmsb(a:b) &= ``0":pmsb(b) \text{ if a=0}\\
&= ``1":pmsb(a) \text{ otherwise}
\end{split}$

Where `:` divides a power-of-two string down the middle or concatenates two strings, depending on its context.

This can already be implemented as a circuit, but it includes some annoying wide comparisons. They can be removed by returning a tuple with an extra bit that tracks the zero-ness of the whole string (it is applied to the halves so you get the result from the halves in the recursion):

$\begin{split}pmsb(``0") &= (Nil, T) \\
pmsb(``1") &= (Nil, F) \\
pmsb(a:b) &= \text{let } (pa, za) = pmsb(a) \\
&\phantom{=}\quad\quad (pb, zb) = pmsb(b) \\
&\phantom{=}\;\; \text{in if } za \text{ then } (``0":pb, zb)\\
&\phantom{=}\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{else } (``1":pa, F)
\end{split}$

This can then be evaluated bottom-up by a circuit of depth O(log n) and size O(n) where n is the length of the bit-string at the top level, which must be a power of two and not one. The zeroness bit circuit has the structure of an AND-reduction, but it is used at the intermediate nodes instead of only at the end. The main result is computed by a similar tree of MUXes that take those bits as control input.

Comment: How to interpret the result of `pmsb`? For `00101100` I get `1010`, using the first version.

Comment: @IllidanS4 drop the bottom bit, but I agree this is a problem. E: fun fact, it did say Nil in my original code. I guess I got fooled by the length=1 case.

Answer (score 6):

The floor of the binary logarithm of $n$ is the integer $i$ such that $2^i \leq x < 2^{i+1}$. This is also the leftmost (most significant) 1 in the binary expansion of $x$. If $x = x_{n-1} \ldots x_0$, then the answer is $i$ if $x_{n-1} = \cdots = x_{i+1} = 0$ and $x_i = 1$. This leads to a simple circuit that computes $i$.